# Eloquent: dynamic fields in "where" clause through variable

Tags: eloquent

I have a dynamic query and need to do a "where" condition that's build dynamically. And if I do this:

```
$fields = 'onefield, another_field, third_field';
$registros = $registros->where($fields);
```

It says

> SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'I

Same thing if I do:

```
$fields = '`one_column`, `another_column`';
```

So, how can I pass a list of fields in this where condition, without looping or calling `->where()` several times?

Answer (score 0):

Ok it's way simple that i thought:

You must pass dynamic columns as array:

```
$columns = array('onefield','anotherfield','oopsanotherone');
```